# SVGs not scaling fully inside iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, svg, matplotlib

So I kinda reaching the end of what 'blind flailing' can accomplish and am hoping someone can point  me in the right direction here.  I am only starting to absorb the whole HTML/CSS way of doing things so still pretty new at this.

So the problem I am trying to solve is one of keeping everything visible on screen.  The page exists mostly for navigating a series of charts produced by matplotlib as SVGs, but is otherwise all static content.

The page is of the basic form:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div name=someFrameName>
            <h2>Some Section</h2>
            <iframe src="some_html_with_controls_and_data_2.html">
                <html>
                    <body>
                       <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href=some_html_with_controls_and_data_1.html>Data Set 1!</a></td>
                                <td>Data Set 2!</td>
                                <td><a href=some_html_with_controls_and_data_3.html>Data Set 3!</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan=3 rowspan=3>
                                    <img src=data_set_2.svg/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

There is also some very basic CSS involved, mostly 'width:100%;height:100%;' and 'table-layout:fixed;', but this is intended to be a rather utilitarian output so there is not much there.

For the most part this works fine, but I run into issues with the content inside the  being longer than what is displayed.  This results in some sections starting before previous ones have finished (so the bottom is cut off) or content continuing below the maximum scroll of the full page.  Often, at minimum, the border for any given table will overlap the text of the next header.

So I am hoping someone can suggest a way to tell the browser 'yes, scale everything inside this div so it displays'.  I have looked a number of similar threads but they all seem to be either much more complicated situations or specifically involve the problem of long text being cut off.

One restriction I should note is that the page can not use any resources external to the site (internet connection can not be assumed) nor can it utilize most java-script libraries due to license issues.  So a lot of the standard convenience libraries are not available in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want your SVGs to automatically scale to fit their containers, then they will need to, at the very least, have a `viewBox` attribute.  Do yours?

Comment: The SVGs are generated so I do not really have direct control over them, but looking at the output they do indeed have viewBox attributes with sane values on them.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the question. If you are trying to automatically scale a long HTML page so that it fits entirely inside a given parent container, then I see no simple way of doing that.  Maybe you could try getting the length of the document with JS, then calculate an appropriate CSS zoom value(??)

Comment: Well, since I did not even know about viewBox before you asked, it was a good thing to clarify.

Hrm. I was hoping to avoid javascript since that would be yet another tech that I am not familiar with to throw in, but that sounds like something I should at least look into.  Kinda surprises me though that a language for laying things out would not have a way to 'fit A inside B'.  hrm.

Comment: Ok, bit of an update.

Looks like the solution was to give up on DIVs+CSS and use HTML tables for layout.

Everything I could find says to use CSS for layout instead of tables, but for the life of me I could not find any combination that would propagate the size of parent containers down the chain in a way that would make this work.  So yeah, nested table.    Wrong solution, but they respect each other's bounds.